# Using Structural Replace in IntelliJ to change field protection level

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm trying to use Structural Replace to flag all private fields as warnings, then suggest to replace them with protected fields.  (I know many people may disagree with my choice of protection levels, but that's a separate issue)

I have the following:

```
class $Class$ { 
 @Modifier("private") $FieldType$ $FieldName$ = $Init$;
}
```

[image]

In "Edit Variables..." I have "FieldName" checked for "This variable is target of the search".

This properly highlights variables that are marked as private.  However, the replacement suggestion is completely wrong:

[image]

How do I modify my Structural Replace settings to suggest making the field protected?

**UPDATE**

I've changed my search/replace strings to be the following, which works significantly better:

[image]

This allows me to replace field definitions such as `private int foo=1` with `protected int foo=1`.  However, it does NOT work with `private static final int foo=1`, which it replaces with `protected int foo=1`  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the modifiers being removed is an old bug in Structural Search & Replace. I have submitted [a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172046).

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success with regular expression replacements using grouping.

SSR is finicky - it only works with actual well-formed code segments... maybe it doesn't support 'static' as a wildcard replacement?